# Add border to every x list starting at a specific number

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if there's a javascript that can add a top border to every fourth < li > starting at a specific number? For example, starting at the 5th < li >, there would be a top border on the 9th < li >, 13th < li >, 17th < li >, and so on.

Currently I'm using the script (below) in order to add the top border using CSS but was wondering if there's a JS instead.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // Adds 'vid#' to each video thumb
        $('.sidebar .content li').each(function(i) {
        $(this).addClass('article'+(i+1) );
        });
    });
</script>
```

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

CSS is a powerful thing:

```
.sidebar .content li:nth-child(4n+5) {border-top:1px solid black}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9Gf3r/)

Comment: Deleted my answer. Didn't know this was possible, definitely the way to go

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Is there a way to make this CSS work for IE7 and IE8? I'm assuming you might have to go to the jquery route...